# Issue of database connection lost getting error 2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

We are facing the database connection error 2013, ‘Lost connection to MySQL server during query’ in the UAT server(LAMBDA). This error is coming randomly like once or twice a week, for the solution I use to push any kind of code (no matter what it can be a comment also) or I restart the database then the problem instantly resolves.

But I’m looking for a permanent solution, please help me to get over of it

Thank you

```
# SSH TUNNEL
try:
    tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder((config('ssh_address'), 22), ssh_pkey = config('tunnel'), ssh_username = config('ssh_username'),
                                remote_bind_address=(config('remote_address'), 3306),local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1',4280))
    tunnel.start()
    print("SSH Started....")
except Exception as e:
    print("==============================================================\nSSH error: \n",e,"\n==============================================================")

host     = '127.0.0.1'
dbSchema = config("schema")
user     = config('user')
passwd   = config('password')
port     = 4280
# port     = tunnel.local_bind_port

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': dbSchema,
        'USER': user,
        'PASSWORD': passwd,
        'HOST': host,
        'PORT': port,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET max_execution_time=10000000'  # In milliseconds
        }
    },
    'oldDB': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'eff_eb',
        'USER': user,
        'PASSWORD': passwd,
        'HOST': host,
        'PORT': port,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET max_execution_time=10000000'  # In milliseconds
        }
    }
}
```